# Integrate mxGraph client-side JavaScript diagramming library with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mxgraph

Is there any possibility to integrate the [mxGraph](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/) client-side JavaScript diagramming library with [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/)?

Stil I have failed to find out any proving solution.

If it's possible please help me to find out some examples.

Thanks.

Comment: There surely is. If there are no existing supporting libraries, you're on your own. It's unclear what kind of examples you're looking for. If you're aware of how AngularJS works, it's very straightforward. Wrap with a directive, synchronize library events with scope digests. Feel free to ask new questions if you will have some *specific* problems with the implementation.

Comment: Definitely possible, we do it.

Comment: I have tried using mxgaph with angular js . But angular.min.js:123 ReferenceError: mxGraph is not defined . How to resolve this